# why is etags generating a corrupted TAGS file?

Tags: emacs, tags, etag

I have the following minimal source file:

```
$ cat path/xx/yy/fooBar.c 
void this_is_a_test(void)
{
}
```

If I run etags like this it works ok:

```
$ etags path/xx/yy/fooBar.c 
$ cat TAGS 


path/xx/yy/fooBar.c,25
void this_is_a_test(1,0
```

But if I run etags via find/xargs the TAGS file is corrupted:

```
$ find . -name fooBar.c
./path/xx/yy/fooBar.c
$ find . -name fooBar.c | xargs etags
$ cat TAGS


path/xx/yy/fBoBar.c,25
void this_is_a_test(^?1,0
```

Note the filename shows up above as fBoBar.c -- bogus!

I like to be able to generate TAGS by doing something like `find . -name '*.[ch]' | xargs etags`. But it is corrupting most of the filenames when I do this.

Any idea why it is failing like this, and/or what I can do to make it work?

Ubuntu Lucid. Etags is from emacs23-bin-common 23.1+1-4ubuntu7.

**Edit**:

In response to fschmitt's question:

```
$ etags $(find . -name fooBar.c)
$ cat TAGS 


path/xx/yy/fBoBar.c,25
void this_is_a_test(1,0
```

**New info**:

I just noticed that the difference between the two uses in my original question above is the leading `.` on the path. And if I call etags like `etags ./path/xx/yy/fooBar.c`, it corrupts the file. So a workaround is to make sure the args to etags don't have leading tags. (Perhaps this is a bug in etags, because the documentation describes my usage pattern almost exactly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that the difference between the two uses in my original question above is the leading . on the path. And if I call etags like etags ./path/xx/yy/fooBar.c, it corrupts the file. So a workaround is to make sure the args to etags don't have leading tags. (Perhaps this is a bug in etags, because the documentation describes my usage pattern almost exactly.)

Comment: If you're not picky, you can pick up all the files (not just .c and .h) with the --recurse option: `etags --recurse .`, at least in http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ ctags-5.8.

Comment: @fearless_fool: Thanks! That option isn't available in the `etags` that comes with emacs, but knowing it exists makes me want to switch to exuberant ctags.

Comment: I don't know if it has any disadvantages, but what about `find $PWD -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' | xargs etags`? This way the absolute paths are handed over to etags.

Answer (score 6):

I am facing here the same problem. However given that you haven't provided the etags/emacs version your using I am not 100% percent we are talking about the same problem.

My etags/emacs version 23.1 and I think there is a bug in etags that is corrupting file names when they are prefixed with a "./". For example I picked up one specific file that its name was being corrupted and generated the TAGS file for it with and without the "./" prefix. The corruption only occurred with the "./" prefix.

My - get around the problem - solution is to cut the "./" prefix before feeding the file names to "etags". Here is how I do it:

```
find . -name '*.[hc]' -print  | cut -c3- | xargs etags -
```

This works for me hope it does for you!

Comment: Version is in the question: `Etags is from emacs23-bin-common 23.1+1-4ubuntu7`.

Comment: I think this is the same as the bug described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs23/+bug/582347. The fix - as of now - has not been ported Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for an alternate recipe, but your workaround is essentially the same as what I answered above -- feed etags filenames without the leading ".".

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helped me. I wonder why this bug still exists, or if it's not a bug.

Comment: Just in case a file happens to be missing the "./", it may be better to use sed to strip the leading "./": `sed "s/^\.\///" |  xargs etags -`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `-` after etags to get it to read from stdin:

```
find . -name fooBar.c | xargs etags -
```

**EDIT:**

Oops, I really should have read the whole question.  I don't know why it is corrupting the filenames.  But you should still use `-` :)

Comment: `xargs` reads from stdin and provides the files to etags as arguments. If I wasn't using xargs, I would need the `-` -- and I've tried that, and it still corrupts the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. What happens if you do

```
etags `find . -name '*.c'` `find . -name '*.h'`
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
etags --members `find ./ | grep [ch]$`
```

HTH.